# Add an image with an embedded link in web part of home page in Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, hyperlink, image, sitepages

I'm trying to add an image with an embedded link but the Hyperlink field is not available when I add the image web part of the homepage.

It was previously available in the previous Sharepoint version or classic view. But classic view is not available for the Homepage.

How do I add an image with an embedded link on the Homepage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Image web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-image-web-part-a63b335b-ad0a-4954-a65d-33c6af68beb2) in SharePoint online modern experience to show image on home page.

You can add hyperlink on image from web part settings like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot! I'm not sure why I am not getting the same options. After adding the image web part and image, the only options available to me are Title, Caption and Alternative Text. Any idea if there are admin settings to allow for more options?

Comment: You are using modern experience, right? Are you using Government tenant or something or normal office 365 tenant?